# How to calculate the probability an individual will get infected

Tags: probability

I'm wondering how to convert R0 (the average number of people an infected person infects) into the probability an uninfected individual in a population will get infected (in time T), if we assume that R0 doesn't change due to transmission mitigation efforts.  Here are the variables that seem relevant:

- R0 = Average number of people an infected person infects
- T  = Time
- D  = Duration of contagiousness
- Pa = Probability an infected individual will be asymptomatic*
- Ia = Relative infectiousness of asymptomatic individuals versus (pre-)symptomatic*
- p  = Population size
- s  = Starting number of infections
- Pt = Probability an individual will become infected in time T

* These are based on a model from the CDC that asymptomatic individuals are 75% as likely to transmit coronavirus as an individual who becomes symptomatic.  My Naive interpretation here is that their R0 is different.  If R0 of a (pre-)symptomatic individual is 2.5, I assume the R0 of an asymptomatic individual would be 2.5*.75=1.875.  I have read though that duration of contagiousness is the same.

Let's also assume that infectiousness (R0) is the same during the pre-symptomatic and symptomatic periods, just to simplify things - even though they may be different.  (The CDC says 50% of transmissions are during the pre-symptomatic period (1-3 days) and 50% are after the first symptom (5-10 days).

So I'd like to know how to calculate Pt.  What would the formula be?  Am I missing any variables?  And what would be the probability given these numbers for the coronavirus?:

- R0 = 2.5
- T  = 1 year
- D  = 13 days (worst-case: upper end of contagious period range of pre-symptomatic (1-3) to after the first symptom (5-10) - though there are exceptions)
- Pa = 0.294 (i.e. 29.4% of infections are asymptomatic)
- Ia = 0.75
- p  = 328.2 million
- s  = 10.5 million (current case count (7.41M) plus an estimate of asymptomatic cases based on Pa: asymptomatic_cases/(7.41+ asymptomatic_cases)=.294)
- Pt = ?

I got these numbers from various sites this morning (10/4/2020).

I don't know how to account for the exponential spread.  And I don't know if I'm making any invalid assumptions, so I'd like some help improving this question in order to reasonably estimate probability of infection without mitigation efforts, like if we were to pretend it didn't exist and go about our lives normally.  I've heard there are problems with using R0 in this regard.  What are the problems with R0?

Comment: Contacts are not *independent* and  random, no hope that such a calculation would match real life.

Comment: @GyroGearloose +1, got that *right*

Comment: That's not the only flaw. I did say "if we assume that R0 doesn't change due to transmission mitigation efforts", which would never happen, so this isn't intending to represent real life. That said, that's a very good point. How does one model contacts?

Comment: Obviously, I'm not a mathematician. That's why I came here to ask people who know how to do this stuff. I'd appreciate it if you can give me some pointers on how to ask this question.

Comment: I regard your query as a very legitimate question, which I have no clue about.  GyroGearloose' comment suggests (and I agree) that the mathematical answer to your question is subject to be extremely complicated.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I may turn it into a general question about factors to consider or how pandemic models are constructed or what thwarts this sort of modeling. Suffice it to say that mortality rate is a very poor measure of how dangerous a disease is. That's only a measure of virulence. R0 is a measure of infectiousness. Those combined would be closer to a holistic assessment. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: And actually, my intent is to compare flu (R0=1.3) with SARS-cov-2 (R0=2.5) using their respective case mortality rates. So perhaps I should add that to the question? Because that's apples to apple and eliminates contact modeling concerns.

Comment: Not really connected to your question but probably in the field of your interests: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3812951/290307

Comment: I was just playing with some numbers and I think maybe I somewhat grasp what you mean by contacts not being independent and random. Does that mean you can't just raise R0 to the power of the number of rounds of transmission to see how many people are infected after N rounds? That, I get. People develop immunity and they have their social groups, thus contacts (i.e. exposures) reduce over time, or rather, look like a bell curve. But in terms of a model, how do you account for that?